# What color is easier to distinguish when drawing multiple curves?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

I am sorry to ask this question. I am using matplotlib library to draw pictures. I need to draw 8 curves in a picture. But I am a bit color weakness. I can't distinguish different colors well, and many colors do not seem to be different in my opinion. If I only draw one or two, I can still choose easily, such as black, red, etc. But drawing eight curves, I can't find eight different colors. What color did you choose for drawing? I want to use this picture in a paper. Is there a recommended color for the paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit [this site](https://mokole.com/palette.html) for instance and then use the Hex Colour Codes for your pictures.